# What is the most appropriate timezone nomenclature to be used as reference CLDR or IANA?

Tags: timezone

I'm researching the most appropriate implementation for timezones in my solution and found 2 main sources of timezone information which nomenclature are inconsistent, IANA and CLDR. I wonder which one is more reliable

See below examples among of 56 countries inconsistencies I found so far

Guinea
IANA: Africa/Abidjan
CLDR: Africa/​Conakry

Gambia
IANA: Africa/Abidjan
CLDR: Africa/​Banjul

Grenada:
IANA: America/Puerto_Rico
CLDR: America/​Grenada

Gabon
IANA: Africa/Lagos
CLDR: Africa/​Libreville

Which one is the correct one and why?

I found that CLDR is commonly used more for Localization purposes than IANA which is more used for geopolitical, compliance, legal and business purposes. I'm wondering if there is a consolidated version of that.

Comment: for some context, the [Common Locale Data Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) provides locale data which includes time zone names, while the [IANA tzdb](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) is a time zone database, i.e. specifies rules for time zones.

Comment: btw. the [timezone tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) is a good read IMHO. The "Time zone Databases" section also mentions CLDR. This should clarify the relation between the IANA db and CLDR.